# GeoServer - restrict access to layer by IP mask

Tags: geoserver, security

Can you restrict access to an individual map layer in GeoServer by an IP mask (eg. 192.17.204.0/32)?  This is as opposed to firewalling the whole service, or by role authentication.

Comment: What is the operating system that geoserver is running on ?
Would get requests satisfy your requirements for access ?

Comment: OS is windows server 2008. No, get requests wouldn't do it.

Comment: http://blog.e-shell.org/25 ,(mod_rewrite) if there is apache in stack

Comment: @simplexio that's a good idea but this isn't on apache so no mod_rewrite. That's something to consider though.

Comment: i vaguely remember, friend who does uses geoserver talked about apache proxy for geoserver. Maybe he had different architecture in use

Comment: Can you add more detail about the whole stack, and also explain why you want to limit access? We can guess, but having it explicit might help to suggest a "good enough" alternative.